# Building the Linux kernel, adding an additional file to the deb package

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian, dpkg

I would like to build this kernel: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.14.y-rt

It's the kernel for the raspberry pi. I would like to build the deb packages which can be done with: `make deb-pkg`.

When installing the resulting packages, a vmlinuz**** file is installed into /boot. The Raspberry Pi needs an .img image tough.

The .img image can be generated using `make zImage`.

Now I just need to find a way to include the .img in the deb packages.

I think this script is responsible for the deb package creation: 
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y-rt/scripts/package/builddeb

Here is what I tried:

```
# ./zImage is the generated .img image
mv ./zImage ./arch/arm/boot/kernel7.img
make deb-pkg
```

It was completely ignored and not included in the resulting .deb files.

I know I could probably just unpack the deb packages, add the file and pack them again, but I think the other files might not be valid then anymore (the `.changes` file for instance).

Answer (score 0):

'debian/rules' is a file that contain build and install instructions. In https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y-rt/scripts/package/builddeb it's definition begins from line 389 to 405. Section 'build-arch' is responsible for finally package build.

```
binary-arch:
    \$(MAKE) KDEB_SOURCENAME=${sourcename} KDEB_PKGVERSION=${packageversion} bindeb-pkg
```

So, you should edit 'Makefile' of this project in target **bindeb-pkg**. In this place resulting package is being produced.

Comment: I found the bindeb-pkg section in this file: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y-rt/scripts/package/Makefile But I don't understand what I would have to add or where I would have to put my files in order to make them appear in the .deb package.

Comment: Try to add ' cp "$tmpdir/$installed_image_path" "$tmpdir/$installed_image_path".img ' after line 143 in file https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y-rt/scripts/package/builddeb.